# Parse by lines by differences of values in a specific column using awk or something similar

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have a tab delimiter file (file1) with 5 columns. I do not want to print lines if differences of values in column 2 are greater than 1 but less than 11.

Here is file1:

```
11 130068214    G   A   Test1
11  133790738   A   C   Test2
11  133790739   A   C   Test2
12  25398281    C   T   Test3
12  25398284    C   T   Test3
12  49418613    C   T   Test4
12  49424177    T   G   Test4
12  49424185    A   C   Test4
12  49434970    T   G   Test4
12  49435227    T   G   Test4
16  2817333 G   T   Test5
16  3781407 T   G   Test6
16  3781413 T   G   Test6
16  3781416 A   C   Test6
16  3781419 A   C   Test6
4   141622708   C   T   Test7
X   107374574   G   A  Test28
```

This is the output that I desire (file2):

```
11  130068214   G   A   Test1
11  133790738   A   C   Test2
11  133790739   A   C   Test2
12  49418613    C   T   Test4
12  49434970    T   G   Test4
12  49435227    T   G   Test4
16  2817333 G   T   Test5
4   141622708   C   T   Test7
X   107374574   G   A  Test28
```

I have tried the following code but that does not give me the desired output:

```
more file1 | awk '{if ($2!<prev) print $0; prev=$2}' > file2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please use CODE TAGS for your shown sample Input_file and expected output in your POSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Your shown output doesn't meet your ask. Considering that you need the difference of previous 2nd column with current second column and its range of difference should be between 1 to 12, if that is the case then following may help you:

```
awk '((($2-prev)>1) && (($2-prev)<=11)) || FNR==1{print} {prev=$2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following code in a file , say in `filter.awk`, and run like `awk -f filter.awk data.tsv`.

```
FNR==1 { prev = $0; prev_num =$2; prev_ok=1 }
FNR>1 {
  d = ($2-prev_num)**2; ok = !(d<121 && d>1);
  #workaround for ignoring sign

  if (prev_ok && ok) print(prev);

  prev_num=$2; prev =$0; prev_ok = ok;
}
END { if (prev_ok)  print (prev); }
```